# Locate TextBox inside GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms

My code below doesn't find the `textbox`:

```
    protected void AddActivityTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox tb = (TextBox)sender;
        string ID = tb.UniqueID;
        TextBox tb2 = (TextBox)GvAddActivityData.FindControl(ID);
    }
```

This is a `textbox` from inside a `GridView` so I must use the `UniqueID` instead of the `ID` property as there is a `textbox` with the same `ID` for each row.

However `FindControl()` returns `null`.

Comment: could you show the GridView markup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to find the TextBox, you have already found it with `tb`. The TextBox invoked this function, and is therefore the `sender` object.

Anything you would be able to do with `tb2` you can already do with `tb`.

Having said that, if you have the UniqueID of the control, you can find it using `Page.FindControl`:

```
TextBox tb2 = (TextBox)Page.FindControl(ID);
```

Comment: Clearly I'm going about this wrong.
I need to establish what row the `TextBox` belongs to so that I can grab an `ID` and update that record using the `ID`.